# Rails 3 translate from errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hi
I'm using the simple_form GEM.
I'm also translating form labels, that is working fine, so 'Name' becomes 'Navn'

But my form error message displays it as 'Name'

Any clue about what's happening?

--EDIT--
I found out that i had to do the following in my translation file:

```
da:
    activerecord:
        models:
          brand: 'brand'
          user: 'bruger'
        attributes:
          brand:
            name: 'Navn'
          user:
            name: 'Navn'
```

I hope some other will find this info usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
da:
activerecord:
    models:
      brand: 'brand'
      user: 'bruger'
    attributes:
      brand:
        name: 'Navn'
      user:
        name: 'Navn'
```